# Find the length of the parametric curve $x(t)=5+6t^4, \quad y(t)=5+4t^6\ , \quad0 ≤ t ≤ 2$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the following parametric curve.

$$x(t)=5+6t^4\ ,\quad y(t)=5+4t^6\ ,\qquad    0  ≤  t  ≤  2.$$

I used the formula
$$\int_0^2\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$
And I found 
$$\frac23\cdot 17^{3/2}+4-\frac23$$
However I got it wrong. I don't know where I went wrong. Any help would be apriciated.

My steps:
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = 24\cdot t^3 $$
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right) = 24\cdot t^5 $$
$$\int_0^2\sqrt{\left(24\cdot t^3\right)^2+\left(24\cdot t^5\right)^2}dt$$
$$\int_0^2\sqrt{\left(576\cdot t^6\right)+\left(576\cdot t^10\right)}dt$$
$$\int_0^2\sqrt{\left(576\cdot t^6\right) \cdot \left(1+t^4\right)}dt$$
$$24+\int_0^2\sqrt{\left(t^6\right) \cdot \left(1+t^4\right)}dt$$

$$\frac23\cdot 17^{3/2}+4-\frac23$$

Comment: What is 6t4?  What is 4t6?  Without seeing your work we can't see where you went wrong.  Answer keys are wrong sometimes.  You should have a square root of the sum of the squares in your integral.

Comment: Please write the mathematical part in mathjax, and show what you have done so far. Here is a link to mathjax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Isn't there a square root missing in your length formula?

Comment: Yes. But I used the square root. I am new to math stack exchange and I couldn't write the mathematical expressions correctly. I am checking the mathjax tutorial from the link which bertrand-wittgensteins-ghost gave.

Comment: Then you want \sqrt{  }.

Comment: There is some similarity between what you got and the correct answer. So you should recheck what you got as an antiderivative. (In fact, you should edit your question to show what you got) and also recheck your arithmetic.

Comment: We probably cannot figure out what you did wrong unless you show the work ending with that as an answer..

Comment: I am trying to write my steps however the mathematical notations I use in MATLAB and here are too different and it is taking some time :(

Comment: @curiouseng At the start of your second last line, is "$24 + $" part what you actually used, or is it a typo as you meant it to be $24$ times the integral?

Comment: @JohnOmielan that’s exactly what’s wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, start from the beginning $$x'(t)=24t^3; y'(t)=24t^5$$

Which gives us:

$$\int_0^2 24\sqrt{t^6+t^{10}}dt$$

Which, when integrated, gives us: $$68\sqrt{17}-4$$

I don't, however, know where you went wrong. It could be either a sign error, or a calculation error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used an online integral calculator to see where I went wrong and it was a basic calculation mistake :( Again thank you for your time.

Comment: @curiouseng You are very welcome, regards!

Answer (score 5):

Line 4 should read $$\int_{t=0}^2 \sqrt{576 t^6 + 576 t^{10}} \, dt.$$  This is a typesetting error.

Line 5 is correct.

Line 6 should read $$24 \int_{t=0}^2 \sqrt{t^6 (1+t^4)} \, dt.$$  The use of the addition sign is incorrect because $24$ is a **factor** in the integrand, not a term.

You do not demonstrate how to proceed from Line 6 to Line 7.  I would complete the computation as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
24 \int_{t=0}^2 \sqrt{t^6(1+t^4)} \, dt
&= 24 \int_{t=0}^2 t^3 \sqrt{1+t^4} \, dt \qquad (u = 1+t^4; \; du = 4t^3 \, dt) \\
&= 6 \int_{u=1}^{17} \sqrt{u} \, du \\
&= 6 \left[\frac{2u^{3/2}}{3} \right]_{u=0}^{17} \\
&= 4 (17^{3/2} - 1) \\
&= 68 \sqrt{17} - 4.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$\begin{cases}x=5+6t^4\\ y=5+4t^6\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}t^2=\left(\frac{x-5}{6}\right)^{1/2}\\ t^2=\left(\frac{y-5}{4}\right)^{1/3}\end{cases} \Rightarrow y=4\left(\frac{x-5}{6}\right)^{3/2}+5\\
0\le t\le 2 \Rightarrow 5\le x\le 101$$
Hence:
$$S=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+y'(x)} \  dx= \int_5^{101} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-5}{6}\right)} \ dx=\\
=\int_5^{101} \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{6}} \ dx=4\cdot \frac{x+1}{6}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{6}}\bigg{|}_5^{101}=\\
=68\sqrt{17}-4.$$